# Why can't .next('li:visible') or .prev('li:visible') not skip invisible elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I am making a selection control that displays a list of options in an 'li' and allows the user to scroll up and down through the li's. Since the li's can be filtered sometimes they will be rendered invisible through a '.hide' giving me the following markup:

```
<input type="text" id="comboBox" />
<ul id="comboBoxData">
    <li style="display:none">1</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>1234</li>
    <li style="display:none">12345</li>
    <li style="display:none">123456</li>
    <li>1234567</li>
    <li>12345678</li>
</ul>
```

I have the following JQuery code to handle the arrow key controls:

```
$('#comboBox').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 38 && e.keyCode <= 41) {
        if ($("#comboBoxData li.selected").length > 0) {
            var current = $("#comboBoxData li.selected");
            if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                $("#comboBoxData li.selected").prev('li:visible').addClass('selected');
            } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                $("#comboBoxData li.selected").next('li:visible').addClass('selected');
            }
            current.removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $("#comboBoxData li:visible:first").addClass('selected');
        }
        $("#comboBox").val($("#comboBoxData li.selected").html());
    }
});
```

with the following CSS to clearly mark which element I have selected:

```
.selected
{
    background-color:Navy;
    color:White;
}
```

My problem is this, in the exampel that I'm giving when the user presses the 'down' button the LI for '12' is being selected and the up and down buttons work correctly for '12' down to '1234' however there they stop and cannot find the '1234567' because of the gap of the two li's that are set to 'display:none'. is there a way around this? maybe an alternative to .next() and .previous()?

Comment: Have you read the manual by chance?

Comment: @close-voter: What makes this question *difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Comment: @Matt I consider this question vague, incomplete and not valid on SO. This is an rtfm question. The manual clearly states the answer if someone cares to read it. I also downvoted because it shows no research effort (I wonder what the upvoter thought... sympathy upvote?).

Comment: @bažmegakapa There's the possibility that the 'upvoter', given that it's not you, and indeed a different person, might have had a 'different' view on how bad my question was.

Comment: @WilliamCalleja That's possible. So you think you should never read the manual, instead you should ask questions like this on SO? Others will look it up for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) or [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) instead.

`next()` and `prev()` will only match the prev/ next element if it matches the selector. `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` searches all next/prev elements for matches.

To select the *first* previous/ next element try;

```
nextAll('your-selector').first()
```

or

```
nextAll('your-selector:first')
```

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity. Is prevAll() sorted by index() asc or by closest index (reveresed)? **EDIT:** Nevermind, found out that they are sorted by closest siblings.

Comment: @RobinCastlin: closest index (reversed).

Comment: Thanks. So `prevAll('your-selector').first()` gets expected one aswell? The same goes with .eq(0) I asume?

Comment: Thanks loads mate, it worked perfectly, all I needed to do was .prevAll('li:visible:first')

Comment: @RobinCastlin: Yeah, because the jQuery set returned is ordered in closest-siblings order, and when you use `eq()`, `get()`, `first()` etc, it's the set order you're addressing, not the position in the DOM .

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're using is for only the next item, and if that item doesnt match the selector, then no item can be returned. You'll need to use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) or [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/pervAll) to collect all the possible elements to be filtered with your selector.

Take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WxAZ/2/